# rearrange php multidimensional array according to id

Tags: arrays, sorting, nested, key

-I cannot figure out how to regroup this array accourding to ids.

- This array comes from a mysql table. the number 17 and 20 are foreign keys in the table.

```php
$orginal_arr = 

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
            [content] => string...?
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
            [content] => hello
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
            [content] => string...?
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
            [content] => string...string...??
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
            [content] => string...
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
            [content] => string...
        )

);
```

**I want to convert the above $orginal_arr array to the following  $desired_arr array.**

```php
$desired_arr = Array (

          [0] => Array
              (
                  [17] => Array
                      (
                          [0] => string...?
                      )
              )
          [1] => Array
              (
                  [20] => Array
                      (
                          [0] => hello
                          [1] => string...?
                          [2] => string... string...??
                      )
              )
          [2] => Array
              (
                  [17] => Array
                      (
                          [0] => string...
                          [1] => string...
                      )
              )

      );
```

so far I am trying the following approach:

```php
function group_by_key($key, $data)
{
    $result = array();
    $j      = 0;
    foreach ($data as $val) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $val)) {
            $result[$val[$key]][$j] = $val;
        } else {
            $result[""][] = $val;
        }
        $j++;
    }
    return $result;
}


$desired_arr = group_by_key("id", $orginal_arr);

$desired_arr2 = array();
foreach ($desired_arr as $index => $item) {
    $desired_arr2 += $item;
}


echo "<pre>";
print_r($desired_arr2);
echo "</pre>";
```

the output:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
            [content] => string...?
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
            [content] => string...
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
            [content] => string...
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
            [content] => hello
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
            [content] => string...?
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
            [content] => string...string...??
        )

)
```

*- Thank you very much.*

Comment: Did you tried something ?

Comment: thanks for the comment. Yes I have...I am still trying but no success yet.

Comment: Ok so post what you have done so far and what are the results so we can try to understand what's wrong in your code.

Comment: @jeremycastelli well...I edited my original question and posted the a little code...but clearly its not the solution.

Comment: Hope there was no misunderstanding here, obviously your solution is not working otherwise you wouldn't be asking for help. There is a lot of people posting requests on SO looking of for a free way to obtain a piece of code. Nobody wants to help those kind of people . So when you post what you tried, you are showing you are not one of this kind.

Comment: Concerning your problem, I didn't code in PHP for years so I used to the exact syntax, but I will post an answer explaining what I would do

Comment: @jeremycastelli..wow..great. I found a solution for this and I posting it as an answer below, thought it works...but I find your approach more elegant,  therefore I mark your answer, the accepted solution.

Comment: glad you found a solution by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, I'm not familiar to PHP syntax anymore so this will be pseudo code.

I would do it in 2 steps,
first I want this result

```
$temp_arr = 

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
            [contents] => Array(
                [0] => string...? 
            )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
            [contents] => Array(
                [0] => hello
                [1] => string...? 
                [2] => string...string...??
            )
        )
...
...
);
```

See, I kept the Object structure with id and contents (with a final S).
then it will be easier to check the id as it is directly accessible

```
$temp_array = Array();

foreach ($original_array as $element) {
    $last = end($temp_array);
    if ($last && $element->id == $last->id) {
        // add to the last $temp_array element
        $temp_array[count($temp_array)-1]->contents[] = $element->content;
    }
    else {
        // create a new $temp_array element
        $temp_array[] = Array(
            "id" => $element->id,
            "contents => Array(
                $element->content
            )
        );
        
    }
}
```

For the second step you just need to iterate the $temp_array and format as you like

Answer (score 0):

here is another solution to this problem.

```php
$desired_arr = array();
$prev_id        = '';
$prev_key       = null;
foreach ($orginal_arr as $key => $value) {
    $this_id = $value['id'];
    if ($this_id == $prev_id) {
        array_push($desired_arr[$prev_key][$value['id']], $value['content']);
    } else {
        $desired_arr[$key][$value['id']] = (array)$value['content'];
        $prev_key                           = $key;
    }
    $prev_id = $this_id;
}
$desired_arr = array_values($desired_arr);
```